# Flutter - Returning items from list that have a property set to true

Tags: flutter

I have a list in flutter with elements. These elements have a property that can be true or false.

I want to map this list and return just the list where the elements are true. This property is a variable of the element object.

```
return StreamProvider<List<CustomElement>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().customElements.map((item) => item.isValid),
      child: CustomElementList(),
);
```

The error I am getting is:

> The getter isValid isn't defined for the class List < CustomElement >

So I am wondering how to write the correct syntax for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return type of stream is List but you are returning isValid, so to return List of bool do following.

change following

```
StreamProvider<List<CustomElement>>
```

To

```
 StreamProvider<List<bool>>
```

Also convert map into list.

```
.map((item) => item.isValid).toList()
```